# How to pass the value to the local scope of the directive?

Tags: angularjs

I'm learning directives, it's cool thing but sometimes a little complicated. Please can somebody explain this:
I have custom directive with template of little form and it own local scope, and want to change the list of items form the main controller. 
Please see it:
By clicking on change button I open a custom directive with input form template

```
 <body ng-controller="testCtrl">
        <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="item in list">
            <div> {{item}} </div>
            <button ng-click="edit()">Change</button>
            <change ng-if='editable'></change>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </body>
```

"Change" is the custom directive with the input form inside the other Html file

```
.directive('change', function(){
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        show: '='
      },
      templateUrl: "other.html"
    }
  })
```

Also there is another directive inside "change" directive. It's a button which I want to use inside "change" directive and inside my main controller. I can see my item list only from scope.$parent.item, but how to pass it in the function of my button directive?
How can I implement this?

```
  .directive('save', function(){
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      replace: true,
      template: '   <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" ng-click="saving(item)">SAVE</button>',
      link: function(scope,element,attr){
        scope.saving = function(item){
        console.log(item); 
        console.log(scope.$parent.item)
        }

      }
    }
  })
```

Please see the example: [Plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/Ni7vSsyPsHuVdnJ5rHzD/preview)

P.S. Sorry for my explanation, I hope that everything is clear

Comment: need to understand that you have multiple scopes happening. First `ng-repeat` creates child scope for each repeated item. Your change directive has isolated scope. The `save` inside `change` is therefore inheriting the isolated scope that doesn't include `item` in that isolated scope. The `save` outside the `change` has access to the item on the child scope of `ng-repeat`. Really important to understand scope concepts. try inspecting them in dev tools

Comment: Suggest you pass `item` into `change` since you isolated that scope. General rule - if you are looking for `$parent` you are probably doing something wrong

Comment: I think I still did not get what is the final result you would be expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass in the `item` to each of your directives that need access to it. For example:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in list">
    //snip
    <save item="item"></save> 
    //snip
</li>
```

And then define your directive to bind the attribute to the scope:

```
.directive('save', function(){
    return {
        //snip
        scope: {
            item: '=' //two-way binding to 'scope.item'
        },
        //snip
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            scope.saving = function() {
                console.log(scope.item); 
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In angularjs, you have the `$emit` event.

> Dispatches an event name upwards through the scope hierarchy notifying the registered `$rootScope.Scope` listeners.
>   [$rootScope.Scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in list">
        <div> {{item}} - <input type="text" ng-model="item">  

        <button ng-click="edit()">Change</button>   
        </div>
       <div>

        <change ng-if='editable'></change>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
```

**Directive**

```
directive('save', function(){
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      replace: true,
      template: '   <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" ng-click="saving(item, $parent.$index)">SAVE</button>',
      link: function(scope,element,attr, controller){
        scope.saving = function(item, index){
          //Build our object with the index of $scope.list which is updated & the item value
        var obj = {
          index: index,
          item: item
        };
        //Emit a 'change' event, and we pass our object data
        scope.$emit('change', obj)
        }

      }
    }
  })
```

In the "change" directive, we use `$emit` to pass event, and to notify our $rootScope.Scope.
In the "change" directive template, you can see that we pass the **$parent.$index** and not the **$index**, in order to get the current item of the list.

**Controller**

```
controller('testCtrl', function($scope){

    $scope.list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

    //Listen for 'change' event
    $scope.$on('change', function(event,value){
      //Set to the list value.index our value.item
      $scope.list[value.index] = value.item;
    });

    $scope.editable = false;

    $scope.edit = function(){
      $scope.editable = !$scope.editable;
    }

  })
```